# Do all the OpenCL optimization-related options default to false?

Tags: opencl, compiler-optimization, compiler-options

An OpenCL implementation compiler takes (see specs for [2.2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_API.html#compiler-options) or [3.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/3.0-unified/html/OpenCL_API.html)), among others, the following command-line options:

- `-cl-single-precision-constant`
- `-cl-denorms-are-zero`
- `-cl-fp32-correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt`
- `-cl-opt-disable`
- `-cl-mad-enable`
- `-cl-no-signed-zeros`
- `-cl-unsafe-math-optimizations`
- `-cl-finite-math-only`
- `-cl-fast-relaxed-math`
- `-cl-uniform-work-group-size`
- `-cl-no-subgroup-ifp`

are these all required by the OpenCL spec to be false by default? If not, do they all have a defined default? Or - does each implementer set its own defaults?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are all false by default if not explicitly set.

According to the [OpenCL specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_API.html#compiler-options): "These options are not turned on by default since it can result in incorrect output for programs which depend on an exact implementation of IEEE 754 rules/specifications for math functions."

Comment: But that quote only regards floating-point-related-options.

Comment: It regardas to all options but -cl-single-precision-constant, -cl-denorms-are-zero and -cl-fp32-correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt. Judging from the context of their descriptions, these remaining three - just like the floating-point-related options - would make absolutely no sense to enable by default.